# How to find Github Repository's committees and their commit counts

Tags: github

I have gone through github documentation and not able to find how to get Github Repository's committees and their commit counts. Does anybody have idea about the same ?

Comment: You may want to specify more what you are looking for. If you are looking for commiters and their commit count for a Git repository (independent from Github) then Mayur's answer gives you that. If you want to get the data from Github, do you mean programatically via the API or via the web page? On the web you can find it under "Graphs" -> "Contributors".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should go to check GitHub Developer API

https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statistics/#get-contributors-list-with-additions-deletions-and-commit-counts

Comment: In this API Response we have a contributions key. wanted to know that refers to commit count ?

Comment: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statistics/#get-contributors-list-with-additions-deletions-and-commit-counts  Here you can check the commit counts

Answer (score 0):

Go to specific branch and fire follow command :

```
git shortlog -s -n
git shortlog -s
git shortlog -n
git shortlog
```

Hope this will help you.